# Python - Pandas : Select rows if a column contains a value in a list

Tags: python, pandas

I've a dataframe from a CSV file which contains a column named `Qualities`.
This column can contain a simple letter or a list with many letters combined. My goal is to extract rows which have at least one value (extracted from an array) in a new dataframe.

I've made this code :

```py
dataframe = pd.read_csv(os.path.join("data", '2019-2020.csv'), sep=",", dtype=columns_types, usecols=columns_to_use, converters={"Qualities": lambda x: x.strip("[]").replace("'","").split(", ")})
search_values = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'AM', 'AMC', 'BM']
mask = dataframe['Qualities'].apply(lambda x: any(item for item in search_values if item in x))

players_df = dataframe[mask]
```

So, I'm getting some results, which are good, but if the column contains *['A', 'Z']*, row is not selected.
And I don't know how to change my lambda function to get this like I want. I know I have to explode the list but I don't know how to do this in the lambda function.

Here is an example if I do a `print(dataframe['Qualities'])`. Could it be a malformation when I use converters params in `read_csv`?

[image]

Can anyone help me please ?

Comment: kindly share a sample data with expected output data as well

Comment: I added some data and I already told what I needed in result

Comment: I've tried with this example: dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'Qualities': [['A', 'Z'], ['TT']]}) and your search_values. Your code selects row with ['A','Z'].

Comment: Well, yes, I tested your code and it's working with the dataframe set ... But not with mine ... Can it come from my read_csv converter parameter ?

Comment: Your converter splits on `', '`. That means that if there is no space following the comma, the split will not work.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I don't understand, as you can see above, there is no spaces after the comma after I opened the CSV and converted it

Answer (score 1):

I guess your code will give you what you want if you change this part:

```
mask = dataframe['Qualities'].apply(lambda x: any(item for item in search_values if item in x[0].split(",")))
```

The thing is that in column "Qualities" you have for example one string value "AF1,DC4" instead of two values "AF1" and "DC4".

Another way to split it is change your converters argument in read_csv as Serge Ballesta points out in his comment.

You have:

```
converters={"Qualities": lambda x: x.strip("[]").replace("'","").split(", ")}
```

and it seems that the right way is:

```
converters={"Qualities": lambda x: x.strip("[]").replace("'","").split(",")}
```